# Does every non-square matrix have both a left inverse and a right inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

That's just it. Let $A_{m \times n}$ be a matrix, does there always exist an $A^{+_{right}}$ and a $A^{+_{left}}$ so that:
$AA^{+_{right}} =  I$
and
$A^{+_{left}}A = I$
?

Comment: No. $rank(BA)\le rank(A)$ for every $B$

Comment: The term is just "left inverse" and "right inverse." "Pseudoinverse" means something else, which always exists and satisfies a weaker condition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix has a "right pseudoinverse" if and only if its rows are linearly independent. A matrix has a "left pseudoinverse" if and only if its columns are linearly independent.

In order for a matrix to have linearly independent rows *and* linearly independent columns, it must be square.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you something more specific? let's say you have an A_m_x_n matrix where m<n, if said matrix is not of full rank, then does this mean it can only have a right pseudoinverse? since if it's not of full rank then it means that not all of the columns are linearly independent therefore it's impossible to have a left pseudoinverse.

Comment: @Nyquist-er In order for a matrix to have *any* pseudoinverse, it needs to have full rank (either row-rank or column-rank). So not only does your $A$ fail to have a left pseudoinverse (which is true for all $m \times n$ matrices with $m>n$), it also fails to have a right pseudoinverse.

Comment: but I said for $m \times n$ where m < n, e.g for a matrix $A_{3\times 4}$, from my understanding (that is, from your comment) a $3 \times 4$ matrix  will definitely not have a full column rank of 4 but it may have a full row rank of 3, so it will succeed in having a right inverse. Is that right?

Comment: You're right, I had a typo